# Django: mock function that is called by other function

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

Imagine that there is a `models.py` file which have `update` and `bulk_update` methods

```
...
@staticmethod
def bulk_update(self, ids):
  for id in ids:
    Foo.objects.get(id=id).update()

def update(self):
  pass
...
```

Not imagine that we have `tests.py` file, where we want to `mock` the `update` method. The problem is that whatever I do, `mock_update` always calls original `update` instead of a mocked one.

TRY #1:

```
# NOT WORKING
@mock.patch('models.Foo.update')
class FooTestCase(TestCase):
  def test_foo(self):
    Foo.bulk_update([1,2,3])
```

Comment: What is `Foo` here?Also you have not passed the `mock object instance` to `def test_foo`

Comment: Seems to me that `bulk_update(...)` should be a class method...

Comment: The most important thing is that ```update``` is not getting mocked.

Comment: When you apply patch decorator you have to pass a mock object